# Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite, python 3.5, re.VERBOSE errors

Tags: python, regex, macos, module, copy-paste

I was trying to make the same like the guy on Lecture 29: Regex Example Program: A Phone and Email from udemy corse. But I got errors and I dont know how to solve this problem and the guy on the video who using Windows doesnt know too. Please help.

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3.5

   import re, pyperclip

   # Create a regex for phone numbers
   phoneRegex = re.compile(r"""
   # 415-555-0000, 555-0000, (415) 555-0000, 555-000 ext 12345, 
   ext. 12345, X12345
   (\d\d\d) | (\(\d\d\d\)))?      # area code (optional)
   (\s|-)                         # first separator
   \d\d\d                         # first 3 digits
   -                              # separator
   \d\d\d\d                       # last 4 digits
   (((ext(\.)?\s|x)               # extansion  word-part (optional)
   (\d{2,5}))?                    # extansion number-part (optional)
   """, re.VERBOSE)

   # Create a regex for email addresses
   emailRegex = re.compile(r"""
   # some.+_thing@something.com

   [a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+  # name part
   @                # @ symbol
   [a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+  # domain name part
   """, re.VERBOSE)

   # Get the text off the clipboard
   text = pyperclip.paste()


   # Extract the email/phone from this text
   extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall(text)
   extractedEmail = emailRegex.findall(text)

   print(extractedPhone)
   print(extractedEmail)
```

And I got this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TheBestOrNothing/Documents/MyPythonScripts/Firstpythonprogram.py", line 15, in <module>
    """, re.VERBOSE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 224, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 293, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 536, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/sre_parse.py", line 834, in parse
    raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 104 (line 3, column 24)
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: It looks like you have too many closing parentheses in the "area code" line.

Comment: Thanks man. You helped a lot! I found a problem. It was the problem with parentheses like you said, but a little bit different. 
I missed parentheses at the start before this code (\d\d\d) | (\(\d\d\d\)))?
and missed parentheses here (((ext(\.)?\s|x). After changed code start working. It should be like this ((\d\d\d) | (\(\d\d\d\)))? and (((ext(\.)?\s)|x) .
Thanks again for quick response.